# What do you call both persons involved in a transaction?

Tags: word-choice

What do you call both persons involved in a transaction?

E.g. Alice gives 5$ to Bob, Bob is a recipient. But what name can I give them both?

Comment: Jochem Kuijpers, writing or saying "How do you call" in your question is awkward and unnatural. The wording "What do you call" is much more common and natural. Your question would be improved, if you edited it to include this.

Comment: @Tristanr Thanks for pointing that out, as you may have guessed.. I'm not a native speaker ;)

Comment: Yes, I noticed that and a lot of other learners asking questions with the "How do you call" wording. Is it normal in your language? One of the benefits of this site is that people can learn more than just the answers to particular questions.

Comment: As a Dutchman myself, I recognize his name to be Dutch. And yes, in Dutch you would say "hoe noem je ..." which could easily end up being translated as "_how_ do you call ..." if one's not careful.

Comment: In both Russian and in Hebrew as well, one would use "how" (как, איך) in place of "what".

Answer (score 36, accepted):

They are *parties* to the transaction.

See *Black's Law Dictionary* (West 1979), p. 1010, which defines "party" (in part) as

> "[a] person concerned or having or taking part in any affair, matter,
>   transaction, or proceeding considered individually."

Comment: +1 - that is more common than participants.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about it, but got really confused..

Comment: Some of the terms in the Commercial Transaction Frame are discussed [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/TIM.pdf) and [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/valueworthpricecost.pdf).

Comment: Very useful when you start talking about "third parties" (Alice gives $5 to Eve to give to Bob), or declining to be a participant ('"I won't be a party to this nonsense!" said Charlie'). Curiously the term is "third party" even when they are in fact a fourth, fifth, etc. In contrast to a third party, the original direct participants are called the "Principals"

Comment: @IainGalloway I think "third party" just refers to the fact that the other parties are directly connected and the "third party" is an outsider, someone who got involved but isn't directly part of the connection.

Comment: I edited your answer because it really wasn't up to the standards StackExchange sites strive for.  As written, your answer appeared to be a good guess.  With the citation to a legal dictionary, it should be better and more deserving of the up-votes you've already received.

Answer (score 5):

"Participants".  'Actors'.  Transactors.

Comment: *Transactors*!?

Answer (score 3):

*[Participants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)*

> Enlisting Resources as Participants in a Transaction

Answer (score 0):

Transaction parties maybe? Not a native English speaker.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage.  In Stack Exchange sites questions and answers should be specific and sourced, ideally, and not just based on opinion or your best guess.  Consider rewriting your answer so that you explain why they would be called "transaction parties" and cite a source that supports your opinion, such as a style manual or a book on language.

Comment: @BruceJames and the 2 downvoters.  The irony is that the post with the highest number of votes contains neither explanation nor any sources with which to back up its "answer". One which was probably based on a hunch and/or personal experience rather than anything else.

Comment: @Mari-LouA -- I agreed with you so much, I proposed an edit to the selected answer so that it can have a source citation.