# What is the optimal word for "either a person, company or other entity"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm making a bookkeeping database table for my personal finances as well as a potential business venture.

I need to name a column which refers to which company or person the transaction is done with. I currently call it "entity" in order to be able to work for "John Doe" as well as "Microsoft", and also the special value "abstract", which I used for the initial record in my table, which simply "sets the bar" of how much money I have in the bank account right now, which means it wasn't really an "income" but something that already exists.

However, "entity" does sound a little *too* abstract, perhaps. Is there a better/more standardized term for this?

Comment: How about `Party`? Inspired by: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/148776/what-do-you-call-both-persons-involved-in-a-transaction

Comment: A juridical person is still a person. John Doe is a person, and Microsoft is a person, too. That said, it's a database column, so you can name it absolutely anything you want, which is why this type of questions is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

I would say
"subject".
According to [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/subject):

- A person or thing that is being discussed, described, or dealt with.

Answer (score 0):

Especially when dealing with transactions, “party” is common.